# Why is \global\let not always global?

Tags: amsmath, grouping

As an LaTeX environment opens a local group, it is normally necessary to use a global definition if changes in the environment should be available after the environment:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multline}
        \gdef\mylabel{text}
    \end{multline}
    \show\mylabel
\end{document}
```

This results in:

```
> \mylabel=macro:
->text.
```

Unfortunately, this does not work with a `\global\let`. Locally, the definition is correct, as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multline}
        \global\let\mylabel\label
        \show\mylabel
    \end{multline}
\end{document}
```

This results in:

```
> \mylabel=macro:
#1->\begingroup \measuring@false \label@in@display {#1}\endgroup .
```

There is no global effect:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multline}
        \global\let\mylabel\label
    \end{multline}
    \show\mylabel
\end{document}
```

This results in:

```
> \mylabel=\long macro:
#1->.
```

Why is the `\global\let` not global here? Is there some (general) work-around to get a `\global\let`?

**Solution (thanks to David Carlisle):**

David Carlisle is correct. As amsmath calls the environment twice and the `\label` command is deleted after the first call, we end up with a deleted command. The solution is to avoid resetting the command in the second call:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multline}
        \ifundef{\mylabel}{%
            \global\let\mylabel\label
        }{}%
    \end{multline}
    \show\mylabel
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm curious to know *why* you want to save the meaning of `\label` in this way.

Comment: @egreg, does my comment to David Carlisle's answer also answer your question?

Comment: Not really, the ams redefinition of `\label` is a very specific redefinition to work in ams alignments. So if you are in an ams alignment `\label` will be defined and you don't need `\mylabel` and if you are not in an ams alignment, you don't want _that_ defintion of `\label`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, contradictory as it may sound, but I do this because multline's `\label` command is very specific. I need to extend it and with the help of the `\global\let`, I can create the extended version once. Afterwards I can just renew the environment and do a `\let\label\mylabel`.

Comment: `\global\let` is still a long winded way of getting the ams definition, which is   `\def\label#1{\begingroup\measuring@false\label@in@display{#1}\endgroup}` you don't need to go into the environment and globally save that definition.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for mentioning, so that others see, that this is a special case. The exact line I am using the code is in a loop over different mathematical environments. For better software quality, I do not want to assume, that the `\label` definition is constant along all environments (I do not think it is) and over all time. The lack of a (La)TeX compiler, which avoids the reexecution of these commands at every (La)TeX run, if the corresponding style files did not change, is another topic.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

AMS alignments are executed twice internally, a first pass to measure the fields and a second pass to typeset. `\label` is given a null definition the second time to avoid duplicating writes to the aux file which would generate errors.

So you do a global let of the real definition but you don't see it as you globally let to the null definition on the second pass.

You can see this by putting `\show\mylabel` inside your `multline` and see it reporting *two* values.  You can use the `\ifmeasuring@` switch to test which pass you are on. and just do the let on one of them.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\makeatletter
    \begin{multline}
  \ifmeasuring@
        \global\let\mylabel\label
    \show\mylabel
\fi
    \end{multline}
    \show\mylabel
\end{document}
```

Produces

```
> \mylabel=macro:
#1->\begingroup \measuring@false \label@in@display {#1}\endgroup .
l.14     \show\mylabel
```

Comment: Moreover, in the first pass `\label` is redefined in a way that's pretty useless outside an alignment environment.

Comment: @egreg, true but not as useless as its definition on the second pass:-)

Comment: @egreg, you are completely correct, the example above does not make sense, but I wanted to keep it short. In a longer example, the `\label` command would again be used in a displayed math environment.